# Peered nodes with no block finalization

Tags: substrate

I'm following this tutorial : https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customchain . In order to create a Private Blockchain Network I've generated the two set of keys, I used the Polkadot UI in order to set the aura and grandpa keys for each nodes (accessing to the nodes through the custom adress putting the right ws-port). I can see the connexion occuring in the terminal. I've successfully have a peer, the nodes communcating with each others but they do not finalized any blocks. Here is what I have in the temrinal of the node 2 (same thing than in the main node).

```
2021-09-10 17:47:14 Substrate Node    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 ✌️  version 3.0.0-monthly-2021-09+1-bf52814-x86_64-linux-gnu    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2021    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Chain specification: Local Testnet    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Node name: MyNode02    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Role: AUTHORITY    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/db    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Local node identity is: 12D3KooWFNeNF8SU4ApDEP2Xv7vKTbNH5rvj5CSEbocLEqWTUJ6f    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Highest known block at #212    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9946.    
2021-09-10 17:47:14 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:60532.    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30334/p2p/12D3KooWFNeNF8SU4ApDEP2Xv7vKTbNH5rvj5CSEbocLEqWTUJ6f    
2021-09-10 17:47:14  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/10.0.2.15/tcp/30334/p2p/12D3KooWFNeNF8SU4ApDEP2Xv7vKTbNH5rvj5CSEbocLEqWTUJ6f    
    2021-09-10 17:47:15 Detected prevote equivocation in the finality worker: Equivocation { round_number: 1, identity: Public(d049754412b60a77530486823eb946a74ef53c0e206943442ee8b47ca11e2c80 (5Gmoe182...)), first: (Prevote { target_hash: 0xce94add9ee3c35a0464432eaf9b4c546f3108cffb7b40bf4be87363c61ac77aa, target_number: 0 }, Signature(d9b95483328e29c83387adf3e9d04fea4aee771c3a643f0c3ec4f9ccee002a603d1bce7328f870d8dcea58b01db6415d99b5fbe33b560e48363dcb0be5bdc908)), second: (Prevote { target_hash: 0x310c432a0daf8e8e47fed164b9bf05fdba70d97d6e438b7707f122d27ce53411, target_number: 85 }, Signature(d48f4a6567833717d2c3904f63ec3652ac3fab6b1244b75f88156335a136a3ff68c7ce8be3b85886460c30de69d61e1d86ed85fbed2a250343c5d3a267909b00)) }  
2021-09-10 17:47:15 Error reporting prevote equivocation: Safety("Refraining from sending equivocation report for our own equivocation.")    
2021-09-10 17:47:19  Idle (1 peers), best: #212 (0xaa7e…ab26), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 0.9kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s    
2021-09-10 17:47:24  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xaa7e37eab14316bf5ffe72d84ba612c51efabb5587c3cd610dae82584557ab26    
2021-09-10 17:47:24  Prepared block for proposing at 213 [hash: 0xef0d7a261c58111bb782fa631fe1f03e137aceb55285ebff8ab2ed0b895fb08c; parent_hash: 0xaa7e…ab26; extrinsics (1): [0x7a22…7b75]]    
2021-09-10 17:47:24  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 213. Hash now 0x5d37cf96116b53988c242dd59adf359cf5525347393652fdeb7a9fa79a6a8526, previously 0xef0d7a261c58111bb782fa631fe1f03e137aceb55285ebff8ab2ed0b895fb08c.    
2021-09-10 17:47:24 ✨ Imported #213 (0x5d37…8526)    
2021-09-10 17:47:24 ✨ Imported #213 (0x5a46…87a9)    
2021-09-10 17:47:24  Idle (1 peers), best: #213 (0x5d37…8526), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2021-09-10 17:47:29  Idle (1 peers), best: #213 (0x5d37…8526), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2021-09-10 17:47:34  Idle (1 peers), best: #213 (0x5d37…8526), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 74 B/s ⬆ 81 B/s    
2021-09-10 17:47:36  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x5d37cf96116b53988c242dd59adf359cf5525347393652fdeb7a9fa79a6a8526    
2021-09-10 17:47:36  Prepared block for proposing at 214 [hash: 0x515dd64ad73edf646c599dd5fdb54be49f3c5f5cbf2b9f9e6572af2c7b7f7c50; parent_hash: 0x5d37…8526; extrinsics (1): [0x1c96…cb13]]    
2021-09-10 17:47:36  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 214. Hash now 0xaf661076ed73d1b6b65cce78b774a56b37a9c67afd31597cf755ba7e19c2d22e, previously 0x515dd64ad73edf646c599dd5fdb54be49f3c5f5cbf2b9f9e6572af2c7b7f7c50.    
2021-09-10 17:47:36 ✨ Imported #214 (0xaf66…d22e)    
2021-09-10 17:47:36 ✨ Imported #214 (0xd7e2…0cf6)    
2021-09-10 17:47:39  Idle (1 peers), best: #214 (0xaf66…d22e), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2021-09-10 17:47:44  Idle (1 peers), best: #214 (0xaf66…d22e), finalized #0 (0xce94…77aa), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

Does someone knows why there is no finalized blocks? Even if I've enter specifivally for each nodes the aura and grandpa keys? (I've restarted the two nodes after putting the keys).

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted all the content of keystore for both nodes and rewrote all the keys one by one and restart the nodes and now it works for me :) !

Comment: Usually, after inserting the keys once your node is running you want to restart the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Block finalization is related to grandpa keys. So Aura block production looks like it is working, but granpa does not. Grandpa uses the `ed25519` scheme so make sure you have submitted the correct scheme type.